# Consciousness and memory as separate entities

Tags: consciousness, memory

Read a article which stated that at birth Consciousness and Memory are separated from each other so that facility of memory can be used when required, use of memory by Consciousness was given the name *mind* by author, they further stated that during growth years Consciousness gets damaged by overlap of memory with it, thus leading to involuntary thinking, in conclusion statement was made stating that separation of consciousness and memory is enlightenment.

Is there any philosopher(s) or school of thought which recognises this theory? I think it is more like a Zen but not sure.

Comment: Your survey of the article sounds rather vague. Please give more details. Does the article give any references for its statements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.